# How to count items matching a condition in angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    completed: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Ninja',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Ninja',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Baby',
    completed: false
  },
]
```

I want to make it such that in the HTML template, I can include {{ count-of-how-many objects-had-name-equal-to-Ninja }}
Is there a way to do this within the HTML template without having to write a function in the .ts file?

Comment: Q: so in this example you want the final HTML to show "4".  Because the array has four elements.  Correct?

Comment: 2, because only 2 of them had the name 'Ninja'.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write function and assign the result to a variable in your .ts; then bind it to your .html ;)

Comment: Or pipe will to the work!

Comment: Do you want to display this whole array or just the count?

Comment: @Rolando What you doing with list in HTML? Iterating?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Any purpose?  You will have to use .ts file to do this as Javascript iteration needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an Filter Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filter",
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!value || value.length == 0) return items;
    return items.filter(
      it => it[field] === value
    ).length;
  }
}
```

In your html `{{ array | filter : 'name' : 'Ninja'}}`

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfno4v)

Answer (score 4):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6aksgb)

ts file

```
  list = [
      {
        name: 'Foo',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Ninja',
        completed: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Ninja',
        completed: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Baby',
        completed: false
      },
    ]  

    getCount(name) {
      return this.list.filter(o => o.name === name).length;
    }
```

In template file:

```
 <p>Ninja Count {{ getCount('Ninja') }}</p>
```

Comment: What is diff between posted answer and your answer?

Comment: As OP said `Without writing a line/function in TS file`

Answer (score -1):

Angular allows for interpolation {{}} (https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) using which you can perform a wide rage of functions which you would otherwise write in a TS/JS file.

However, using interpolation to compute results in this manner is not advised. It is always a good practice to keep your components clean. Keep the programming restricted to TS files as much as possible. Compute the length in the TS file and call the result in HTML.